# How to ensure calls are done serially in swift3 app using GCD

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, grand-central-dispatch, ios-multithreading

I need this block of code to run in order:

```
UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
loadDataTask.resume()
UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

It's being run inside of `DispatchQueue.main.async()` (every network call is that's why I'm trying to temporarily block user input). I am still learning swift and struggling a little with the GCD concept. Any recommendations would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Tried [OperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operationqueue) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the `endIgnoringInteractionEvents` call inside the completion handler of `loadDataTask`.

```
UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
let loadDataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    ...

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // do all UI and model updates here

        UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    }
}
loadDataTask.resume()
```

Comment: That works perfectly! I thought I had tried this, but apparently not, thanks so much